# CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed (Same error again and again)

Tags: c#, android-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

Unity version = Unity 2018.2.10f1
JDK = jdk1.8.0_191

PROBLEM:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.  C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.3.0f2\Editor\2018.2.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar"
>   org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m"
>   "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

  > A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.
  >   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.0.1).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.0.1/manifest-merger-26.0.1.jar
  >   Could not find ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.0.1).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.0.1/ddmlib-26.0.1.jar
  >   Could not find dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:26.0.1).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.0.1/dvlib-26.0.1.jar
  >   Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.0.1).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/26.0.1/common-26.0.1.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 1s ] stdout[
>
> ] exit code: 1 UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun
>   (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava
>   (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1
>   progress, System.String error) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run
>   (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String
>   workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress) Rethrow as
>   GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run
>   (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String
>   workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

1)I have tried Changing the manifest for target sdk ...
2)clearing the gradle folder in user..
3)downgraded some sdk 
Still can't build ...same error again and again.

Comment: Have you read https://forum.unity.com/threads/gradle-build-error-gradle-version-2-10-is-required-current-version-is-4-0-1.499520/ and checked the gradle version as it suggests

Comment: Just upgrading it to Unity 2018.3.0f2 solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just upgrading it to Unity 2018.3.0f2 solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

May be late, but I've fixed that issue by deleting the `playcore.arr` file from `Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.core/Runtime/Plugins`

[image]